# How to change build directory in Ionic 3 build process?

Tags: build, progressive-web-apps, ionic3

I'm developing a PWA using Ionic 3.

Normally the JavaScript files generated by the build to browser process of Ionic 3 are in www/build folder.

I wish to change this folder to www/build/v1 and, of course, keep the application working.

How could I change the build process of Ionic 3 to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is add "config" section to your package.json

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  ...,
  "config": {
    "ionic_www_dir": "www/v1",
    "ionic_build_dir": "www/v1/build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
...
}
```

You can read "**Custom Project Structure**" here [ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/app-scripts/).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the [`config`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#per-package-config-settings) option in the `package.json` file to provide custom build configuration.

To get started, add a `config` entry to the `package.json` file. From there, you can provide your own configuration file.

Here's an example of specifying a custom configuration:

```
"config": {
    ...
    "ionic_rollup": "./config/rollup.config.js",
    "ionic_cleancss": "./config/cleancss.config.js",
    ...
  },
```

You may want to see this [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/app-scripts/) for more information.